# ReDJ plugin fom Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3 migrating (nothing displays in admin panel)

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I had **ReDJ plugin** v 1.6 working on **2.5 Joomla** site. But I'm moving on **Joomla 3** and this module don't work now - exception errors appears. In change-logs I found this:
`Changed class names for ALL models, controllers and views`. So I simply add `Legacy` suffix to all classes that handles exceptions. And also change `JRequest` (it is deprecated in v3) on `$input=JFactory::getApplication()->input;`.

So for now, seems like all is working fine. Except.. component admin panel - **i can see component menu, but there is no any content on page**.
Here is screenshot: http://tinyurl.com/btfzxux

Main controller `controller.php` code:
http://pastebin.com/vQjYvYkK 
Main component file `redj.php` code:
http://pastebin.com/gF6icdE3

I found that dont work line `parent::display();` in `controller.php` file. And there is no error in logs and display.
And this line calls `JControllerAdmin->display()` which is:

```
/**
 * Display is not supported by this controller.
 *......................
 *......................
 */
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = array())
{
    return $this;
}
```

So nothing displayed. I tried to rename `extends` definition as `JControllerLegasy` (because it supports display() method), but still nothing in component output.

How can i output component content in admin panel in Joomla 3?

Any help appreciated.
S.G.

**UPDATE 1:**

I publish my code on GitHub. I'm tying to optimize this plugin for **Joomla 3**. Any help welcome!
https://github.com/staniaslavg/ReDJ

*P.S. Now redirection list displays and adding a new one works fine. But.. there is no items in item list.*

**UPDATE 2:**

Finally, everything works fine (tested jnly by me, but seems like everything is OK..)

*P.S.* If nothing displays in tabs - check for DataBase columns. I added a few more. Check whis by var_dump errors variable (like `$this->get('Errors')`) in files `views/.../view.html.php`

***Code on GitHub***: **https://github.com/staniaslavg/ReDJ**

Comment: Did you check http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1

Comment: @ValentinDespa as I said: `in change-logs I found`.. So i really read all that changes and fix all issues.

Comment: Did you also rename JView in JViewLegacy?

Comment: @ValentinDespa Yes, I am sure, that i rename all classes with "Legacy".

Comment: Share your whole code on github so that I can see everything. If we get it fixed, maybe others are also interested and the maintainer will merge it.

Comment: Also, now i have output. But it doesnt shows properly. What i did? I just do that way: 1. rename class as `JControllerLegacy`. 2. delete lines with eror blocking in output form like that: `if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) { return false; }`. So i have output now and it really works. But with errors.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. It'll take a few minutes.

Comment: @ValentinDespa https://github.com/staniaslavg/ReDJ/

Comment: @ValentinDespa check for  question Updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've posted some updates in the github repo, to show that it's possible to get it working. (for the redirects view sequence). Unforunately some code used in Joomla! 2.5 by the component was already deprecated and was removed in 3.0. Also the GUI looks bad in 3.0, it needs more work.

**As much as I would like to help you to get it running, the time involved it huge. I would strongly suggest using Joomla! 2.5 which is still for a good period supported.**

**Also the developer announces that a [Joomla! 3.0 version is underway.](http://www.selfget.com/forum/redj/393-rejd-for-joomla-3-0.html)**

Going over all the code and fixing it makes little sense for me, but here are **some examples:**

**JDatabase::getEscaped() has been removed. Use JDatabase::escape() instead.**

`$db->getEscaped($orderCol.' '.$orderDirn)`

=> `$db->escape($orderCol.' '.$orderDirn)`

**JToolBar no longer supports the 'X' functions (eg, addNewX, editListX) that hide the main menu before doing the function.**

and others.

Comment: hm.. seems like i missed this two "example" issues. thanks a lot! i'm gonna doing it further in that way.

Comment: i fixed some other issues so now all is OK i think. i mean component finally and completely migrated for "Jommla! 3".

Comment: Great. Please be aware that the version that you used was 1.6.X. The latest version for 2.5 is 1.7.X Check with a program like WinMerge what other differences there are.